# ¿Cómo detecto si un usuario selecciona una parte de un texto en un control TextField?

Tags: javafx

Quiero saber cuando un usuario selecciona una parte de un texto dentro de un control `TextField` en `JavaFX` para poder controlar lo que se introduce en él.

He probado con el método `textProperty()` pero sólo se activa el escuchador cuando intento editar el texto sin haberlo seleccionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes añadir un listener a la propiedad `selectedTextProperty` de tu control de texto de esta forma:

```
controlTexto.selectedTextProperty().addListener((final ObservableValue<? extends String> ov,
final String selecciónAnterior, final String selecciónActual) -> {
    System.out.println ("Parte seleccionada: " + selecciónActual);
});
```